# Json.NET DeserializeObject DataSet issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

jsonData is

```
{
  "S_Client.packet": [
    {
      "DESC": "2",
      "NO": 2,
      "SEND": [
        {
          "PARAM": "1",
          "TYPE": null,
          "VALUE": "11"
        }
      ],
      "RECEIVE": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want get data set using method( JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData) ) but "RECEIVE":[] < last character run Exception..

different types was well done..

and not first data(DataTable in DataSet and blank array) was also well done..

I think that was bug to report

Comment: What exception do you get and how does your class you try to deserialize to look like?

Comment: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: EndArray. Path '['S_Client.packet'][0].RECEIVE', line 13, position 19

Comment: and exception is Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException